# How to find place of burial or cremation in Gloucestershire?

Tags: england, gloucestershire, 1970s, burial-records

I am trying to locate where my Grand dad is buried/cremated.

He died on 31st March 1972 and lived in Almondsbury, Gloucestershire, England.

What other sources are there for the area I could check to find this information?

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3207/104 should also be helpful

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I've started a question on Meta -- see http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2046/1006

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions for you in the local area that may narrow down your search:

Gloucestershire county archives are largely kept at the [archive office](http://www.gloucestershire.gov.uk/archives/article/107703/Archives-Homepage) in Gloucester.

Almondsbury nowadays is pretty much just a suburb of Bristol, which has its own [archives](http://www.bristolmuseums.org.uk/bristol-record-office/).  These include local cremation records, which may help if your Granddad was cremated in a Bristol crematorium.

Almondsbury comes under the diocese of [Bristol](http://www.bristol.anglican.org/), which keeps church burial records.

There are online and in-person searches possible at each of these.